# Installation Creator that downloads files from a website

Tags: installation

Would anyone be able to refer me to a installation creator that allows me to specify where it should download the rest of the files from, and if the user already has the file, just skip that file? I need it for, mainly, patching purposes. It just needs to check if the user has a file, and if he/she doesn't, then it downloads it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One choice would be [NSIS](http://nsis.sf.net) - write a macro or function or whatever to check for the existance of a file and download it if it's not there and use that for each file (you can always choose to use a list read from a file).

Answer (score 0):

Try InstallJammer - http://www.installjammer.com